# How do I prevent iTunes TOS prompt?

Tags: itunes

iTunes has been popping up several times per day asking me to accept or decline their TOS.  I have declined for the past 5-ish years (2.5 years on this laptop in particular) because it is not a piece of software that I want or need.

Previously, it was a one-time decline, and I wouldn't see it again.  However, there must have been an update to the software that is causing it to pop up nonstop.  It is extremely frustrating, especially since I can't just drag the app to the trash bin.

How can I stop this from happening?

**Edit:** 3 popups so far today, and it's 10am.  :rage:

Comment: Why don't you just accept it & never look at it again? What's the philosophical difference?

Comment: Because I don't want to blindly accept TOS for something I don't intend to use.

Comment: If you don't use it, what difference does it make?

Comment: I can't tell if you're trolling me.  That's not a helpful response.

Comment: No, I just don't get the foil-hat paranoia bit. Agree to the ToS it will go away. Never use the app, it will make no difference to your life whatsoever.

Comment: It's not "foil-hat paranoia".  I'm done with this comment thread and will await real answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling iTunesHelper.app:

1. Remove iTunesHelper from Login Items.
2. Rename iTunesHelper.app in `/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/` to something else (e.g. iTunesHelper-disabled.app).

Comment: Ahh, didn't know that was in there.  Thank you!